# Maximum stack depth exceeded problem in many to many toArray() overriding

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

i have 2 models, **User** and **Department**. these two have **many to many** relation with each other. when i try to relation field to **toArray()** method inside Model class, i get **Maximum stack depth exceeded** error.

**Department Model :**

```
class Department extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $arr = parent::toArray();
        $arr['users'] = $this->users;
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

**User Model :**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class);
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        $arr = parent::toArray();
        $arr['departments'] = $this->departments;
        return $arr;
    }
}
```

what is the right way to have this kind of JSON output?

/api/departments :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "caption": "asd",
            "status": "active",
            "users": []
        }
    ]
}
```

/api/users :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "username": "asdasd",
            "email": "m@m.m",
            "status": "active",
            "departments": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: use $this->getAttribute('users'); instead of $this->users I'm not sure about it but try it.

Comment: Please can you add your controller code for both routes

Answer (score 0):

In doing what you're doing you're basically going to create an array that will go on indefinitely.

Firstly, remove the `toArray()` methods from both models, there are very few reasons to actually override this method.

To achieve what you want you can simply load the relationships using [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) when you need them e.g.

```php
public function show($id)
{
    return User::with('departments')->findOrFail($id);
}
```

If you're using [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding) or you've just already retrieved the model you can use [load()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) (lazy eager loading) instead:

```php
public function show(User $user)
{
    $user->load('departments');

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: what about array of all departments?

Comment: @MiladHeidari For all departments I wouldn't actually attach it to the user. I would instead return an array like `return ['user' => $user, 'departments' => Department::all()]`;

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
public function with($id, $relations, $columns = ['*'])
{
    $query = $this->model->newQuery();
    $query = $query->with($relations);
    return $query->find($id, $columns);
}
```